# Browser cache downloadable file

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, caching

Say i store pdf files in the database (not important). The users of the application visit a page periodically to grab a stored PDF and print it - for adhesive labels btw.

I am annoyed at the thought of their downloads directory filling up with duplicates of the same document over time since they will download the PDF every time they need to print the labels.

Is there a way to instruct the browser to cache this file? Or any method of relative linking to the users file system possibly? All users will be on Chrome/Firefox using Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: your only option are the http cache-related headers, and at best they're SUGGESTIONS to the browser that the material being downloaded should be cached. Your site cannot force the client to do anything, nor use any user-side local data. That sort of ability would make it trivial to steal arbitrary files from the user's filesystem. You could look into HTML5 localstorage, but then you'd be producing pdfs client-side

Comment: I use the Content-Disposition: attachment; ... btw.

Comment: don't these browsers simply open the .pdf file and not download it? last time I checked they did!

Comment: It won't always be a PDF. It was just an example.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey: everything is a download - it's just that sometimes the final destination is the rendering window of a browser instead of saving directly to file.

Comment: @MarcB his question is how to prevent "downloads directory filling up with duplicates of the same document" your talking semantics of how the browser handles the file, hes talking about preventing something that is ultimately the end users problem, there is no solution for what he is asking the answer below is not correct either, he doesn't care about bandwidth or localstorage or anything like that

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey I like that idea - but what if i sent everything  without specifying it as an attachment? Some would open in the browser, but how would the others be handled?

Comment: turns out it downloads as a file still if Chrome can not parse it. But with the last part of the URL as the file name. That could work.

Comment: btw @MarshallHouse i think you have a great idea here that most browsers/servers are not implementing ... if I have clicked a previously downloaded file in my browser, from the same source, the browser/server should hash it to determine if its different from the file I downloaded an hour ago, 4 hours, a weeks, a month a year, and pull up the same file if said file is there. or atleast give you the option "you have previously downloaded this file you like to download it again or open the previously downloaded document."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a useful solution to my problem.

From the comments on my question, we concluded it would work best to utilize the browser's built in PDF/DOC renderer and download anything else that isn't recognized.

I read this standard: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266

This is the solution (header):

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=something.pdf
```

Instead of attachment, I've used "inline" in order to utilize the browser when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Etags will help you to do this. If the file hasn't been updated since the client last downloaded, the server will send a 304 "not modified" response, instead of the file.

If your files are dynamically generated, you will need to manually implement etag generation in PHP rather than relying on the web server.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-cache-etag.php

Comment: I'm wondering if the download bar will still come up in chrome with a file that already exists in your downloads folder. In the case you provide an Etag

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this is basically how this AWS S3 guide does it: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx2C4WJBMSMW68A/Streaming-Amazon-S3-Objects-From-a-Web-Server

Answer (score -2):

Most browsers will do this automatically based on the URL.  If the URL for a particular PDF blob is constant, the browser will not re-download it unless the server responds that it has changed (by way of HTTP fields).

You should therefore design your site to have "permalinks" for each resource.  This could be achieved by having a resource-ID of some sort in the URL string.

As others have said in comments, a server cannot guarantee that a client does ANYTHING in particular; all you can offer are suggestions that you hope most browsers will treat similarly.

Comment: I am using a typical GET link that has no query string. It still hits the server. I'm not too worried about the server being hit anyway. I'm annoyed by the possible build up of downloads on the client's computer.